# A JQuery progress bar to show something is happening on a page

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery-ui, progress-bar, code-behind

I've got a report page in my application and there's no indication a report is running when you press the button.  So I want to add some indicator, sort of like the old hourglass mouse cursor in Access.  But I decided to try to use a JQuery Progress Bar instead.

I went to the official JQuery Progress Bar page and found some code to integrate into my project.  What I have is this on the ASPX page:

**In the header:**

```
<!--//**********************************
    // Test Indeterminate Progress Bar
    //**********************************  -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    //Total out of range dialog
    $(function () {
        $("#progressbar").progressbar({
            value: false
        });
        $("button").on("click", function (event) {
            var target = $(event.target),
                progressbar = $("#progressbar"),
                progressbarValue = progressbar.find(".ui-progressbar-value");
                progressbar.progressbar("option", "value", false);
        });
    });

</script>  
<style>  
    #progressbar .ui-progressbar-value {    
        background-color: #ccc;  }  
</style>
```

**In the body:**

```
<div id="progressbar" style="visibility:hidden"></div>
```

So now, what I'm expecting to do is to make some call in the code-behind in the OnClick event of a button, to make the progress bar visible, and then when the code has completed running I make it invisible again.

First of all, is that the correct assumption?  And second of all, how would I do this?  Intellisense isn't recognizing "progressbar" as an object.

Comment: Your assumption is incorrect. You can't update the UI directly in code behind, code behind runs on the server and UI updates happen when the server returns an updated page to the browser, javascript runs in the browser. If you want things to happen on the server and a progress bar in the UIU you need to make an ajax call to a web service. There are a couple of hacky ajax enabled controls you could use for this `UpdatePanel` and `UpdateProgress` they are a clunky and heavyweight but generate all the client side code for you.

Comment: Agreed on the incorrect assumption. The best way to do this is create a service that is called via the UI (in your case jQuery) and performs the update. Here are 2 examples that might help:
http://jqueryasp.net/upload-multiple-image-file-progress-bar-asp-net-using-jquery/

http://jqueryasp.net/show-progress-bar-asp-net-using-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

Being that the progress bar wasn't actually going to show progress, I opted to go with an animated GIF using asp:UpdateProgress:

```
<asp:UpdateProgress ID="rptUpdate" runat="server" 
                    AssociatedUpdatePanelID="upReports1" DynamicLayout="true">
    <ProgressTemplate>
        <img src="images/Animated.gif">
    </ProgressTemplate>
</asp:UpdateProgress>
```

It just made more sense for my implimentation.